# P4Python - Create a pending changelist and keep default pending

Tags: python, perforce

I use

```
change = P4.fetch_change()
change['Description'] = Description
result = p4.save_change(change)
```

but it will move my default file into this changelist.

is there has any way to just create empty pending changelist and keep my file in the default?

Comment: Yes there is a way. There's nothing wrong with your snippet; it doesn't move files from "default" to the new changelist. What _else_ are you doing? Can you post more code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A numbered pending changelist is created by saving a changelist 'form', which in your program is identified by the Python 'change' variable.

The contents of this changelist form are up to you, but in this particular snippet you are populating the changelist form by running the P4Python `fetch_change()` method.

That is, you're asking Perforce to create a pending changelist form for you.

When you ask Perforce to create a pending changelist form for you, it will automatically include all of the files that are open in your default changelist as part of the new changelist form.

But that is not required; that is just the default behavior.

Here, it is instructive to run `p4 change -o` from the command line, with several of your files already open in the default changelist. You will see that Perforce automatically includes those files in the generated pending changelist form.

If, instead of running `P4.fetch_change()` to initialize your pending changelist form, you create your pending changelist form from scratch, you can create a pending changelist form which has **NO** files in the form, and then your new pending changelist will be empty (that is, it will contain no files).

Or, you can run `P4.fetch_change()` to initialize your `change` variable, but then before you call `save_change` you can remove the files from the change variable, and leave only the description and other identifying information in the form.

Either way, the important thing is that when you call `save_change()`, the files that will be included in the change are the ones which are in the form that you provide, so simply ensure that the `change` variable has the correct contents.

Lastly, if you get the wrong files in the pending changelist, you can always change that later, prior to submit. For example, the `p4 reopen` command is a convenient way to move files from one pending changelist to another (or to and from the default changelist).